# Is it possible to install a bootable linux installer's payload into a docker container?

Tags: docker

Let us say that I have a bootable ISO or USB image that is designed to install a customised Linux OS payload onto a bare metal machine or overwrite a previous OS and replace it with the payload.

Is it possible to install the payload into a Docker container or create a Docker image based upon the payload?

I expect that this won't be possible to do using `docker build` due to  `build`'s lack of a `--privileged` flag, but can it be done into a container?

I could examine the bootable image and in theory extract the payload manually - *if* the ISO contains human-readable code such as bash scripts from which the payload can be deduced and extracted - then install it to a `FROM scratch` image, but is there any way to automate the process, i.e. build a Docker container which will take a bootable ISO and output the deployed OS in a new image or container, without the user needing to know what is in the ISO and how it must be extracted and installed?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Slightly longer answer: You'd have better luck using libvirt to generate a real guest VM that could be installed onto, then using libguestfs to copy content out of that into somewhere Docker could get into it -- but even then, building a truly generic solution is nontrivial.

Comment: If you can assume an unattended install from the iso then its not that hard to boot an iso and install and the export qcow > tar > `docker import` or `docker build`.. but getting an unattended/generic install is the hard bit.